# How can I construct and interact with a dynamic (ActiveX) dialog using OLE on Windows?

Tags: windows, activex, ole

I have looked at the Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library (FM20.DLL) and Microsoft Windows Common Controls (comctl32.dll), as both exist (I think) as OLE providers on my system. (I am doing this by opening them in VBA in Excel to look at the libraries with their members) and playing around with them in VBA.

My bigger problem is that I don't understand the relationship between the libraries themselves and ActiveX - how do I know which members can be created as ActiveX objects? (For example, you can create "Excel.Application", but not "MSForms.UserForm").

I want to be able to script (using OLE) a form using some library, display it, respond to events, etc. I would prefer using something that is already available (like the libraries mentioned above, if possible) to prevent having to install extra software.

If you can give an example (in any language) to get me started, that would be very helpful and much appreciated.

Comment: Hard to make sense of this question, it is never a practical problem.  ActiveX controls are the ones that show up in the visual designer's toolbox.  Yes, Forms 2.0 has one and it is built into Excel and lets you do all the things you want to do.  Sounds like you just haven't found it yet.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, based on your comment and a tool called ActiveXHelper, I managed to find e.g. "Forms.Frame.1" as an ActiveX object I can create. How would I know, though, that that is the name of the object, as opposed to "MSForms.Frame" or something else? I'm guessing you need access to the ActiveX registry to tell you these things?

Answer (score 0):

As per HansPassant's comment, what worked is using MS Forms 2.0, which has an ActiveX object, "Forms.Frame.1", which can be created and used in my program.

I found a program called **ActiveXHelper**, which allows one to see all the registered ActiveX objects on the system.